# Make NICE web image galerry for android web view

Tags: android, image-gallery

i made android application. In application i have web view where i want to show image gallery. For web view i use wurfl and php. How to make image gallery(jquery, flash or other)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery Ui and Jquery mobile would be a good place to start - they may even have a widget for a gallery.

jQuery sites of interest:-

http://jqueryui.com

http://jquerymobile.com/